# How can I use variables with an HTML5 progressbar?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<progress id="bar" max="25" value="5"></progress>
```

As you can see the max is a integer, so is value.
How can I change the progress bar in order for it to be compatible with variables.

For example:

```
<progress id="PROGRESSBAR" max="VARIABLEMAX" value="VARIABLEVALUE"></progress>
```

This isn't working:

```
<progress id="expbar" max="upcost" value="clicks"></progress>
<script>

    document.getElementById("expbar").setAttribute("max", upcost);
    document.getElementById("expbar").setAttribute("value", clicks);

    var clicks = 0; // How many clicks you have
    var upgrades = 0; // How many upgrades you have purchased
    var upcost = 25; // How much the upgrades cost
```

Comment: Do you generate the element using JavaScript?

Comment: because your variables are defined after the calls, as it is upcost and clicks are `undefined` when you try to use them.

Comment: Even if I put the doc.getEleById... after variables, it still doesn;t work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery this works:

```
var v = 25;
$("#bar").attr("max", v).attr("value", v);
```

with JavaScript this should work:

```
var v = 25;
document.getElementById("bar").setAttribute("max", v);
document.getElementById("bar").setAttribute("value", v);
```